# TItanium Studio - iOS - ListView with label-child

Tags: ios, listview, titanium

My problem is the following: I have a listview in which I need to dynamically load a set of labels (of which I do not know the length), the height of each child of the listview (ie each label) should change according to the length of the label, but unfortunately I do not know how to do

[image]

Test - Code

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

var template = {
    childTemplates : [{
        type : 'Ti.UI.Label',
        bindId : 'label',
        properties : {
            left : 0,
            width : 300,
            height : 'auto',
            textAlign : "left",
            color : "red",
            font : {
                fontSize : 12
            },
            backgroundColor : "#42de0b"
        }

    }]
};


var tabella = Ti.UI.createListView({
        width : 300,
        height : 300,
        separatorColor : 'transparent',
        backgroundColor : 'transparent',
        separatorInsets : {
            left : 0,
            right : 0
        },
        showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
        templates : {
            'plain' : template
        },
        defaultItemTemplate : 'plain'
});


var data_record = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    data_record.push({

        label : {
            text : "test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test "
        },
        properties : {
            selectionStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.ListViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE,
            height : 20
        }
    });

}


var intestazione = Ti.UI.createListSection();
tabella.sections = [intestazione];


intestazione.appendItems(data_record, {
    animationStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.RowAnimationStyle.TOP
});

win.add(tabella);

win.open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set height of ListView template to [`Ti.UI.SIZE`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-SIZE) instead of `'auto'`.

```
var template = {
    childTemplates : [{
        type : 'Ti.UI.Label',
        bindId : 'label',
        properties : {
            left : 0,
            width : 300,
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            textAlign : "left",
            color : "red",
            font : {
                fontSize : 12
            },
            backgroundColor : "#42de0b"
        }

    }]
};
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try as soon as possible and let you know

Comment: If I may ask another question, I would ask you why still see the "separator" (with white background), also setting separatorColor: 'transparent',

Answer (score 1):

try to give `height : Ti.UI.SIZE` to your `properties` instead of `height : 20` and also set the height of `childTemplates` to `Ti.UI.SIZE` instead of `auto`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data_record.push({
        label : {
            text : "test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test "
        },
        properties : {
            selectionStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.ListViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE,
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE
        }
    });
}
```

by doing this I got this result:

[image]

Hope this will help you.. :)